# Identify blue/translucent jelly-like animal on beach

Tags: species-identification, zoology, marine-biology, invertebrates

A few weeks back a beach in California had lots of this animal (if it is an animal?). Can anyone identify what it is?

They had a distinct blue bottom and a see-through top.

[image: Animal on beach]

[image: Animal on beach again]

Comment: Hey, funny seeing this question here. My wife and I just visited a beach in San Diego yesterday and also noticed these creatures. At the time I just Googled "flat animal on beach with fin" and found out it was by-the-wind sailors as someone already answered. They are very alien looking. Wonder what caused them to come to shore in such large numbers.

Comment: With billions of years to work with, evolution comes up with some truly amazing and beautiful creatures.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### By-the-wind sailors

This appears to be [***Velella***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velella) (a [monospecific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotypic_taxon) genus), commonly referred to as **by-the-wind sailor**.

- More specifically, this is *Velella velella*, and is also less commonly referred to as sea raft, purple sail, or little sail in addition to usually being called by-the-wind sailor or even sometimes simply Velella.

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Velella_in_California_April_2020.jpg)</sup>

As can be seen from the above image, this 40-80 mm long [[source](http://sio-legacy.ucsd.edu/zooplanktonguide/species/velella-velella)] organism has a translucent sail with a lower bluish body that includes (not visible in your image or mine) small tentacles -- see below (as well as [here](http://sio-legacy.ucsd.edu/zooplanktonguide/species/velella-velella)):

[image]

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velella#/media/File:Velella_Bae_an_Anaon.jpg)

For more detailed description, see [Scripps Institution of Oceanography](http://sio-legacy.ucsd.edu/zooplanktonguide/species/velella-velella):

> A clear, chitinous semicircular to triangular sail sticks up above the water with a blue float beneath made of concentric circles of gas-filled chambers. Small tentacles extend below the circular chambers. The sail is angled left or right.

Like the better-known [man o' war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_man_o%27_war) (see below), this carnivorous [hydrazoan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrozoa) (think hydra or other related [cnidarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cnidaria) like jellyfish), floats on the water's surface, using wind to direct its small, rigid sail while dangling tentacles below armed with [nematocysts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cnidocyte) catch and stun prey. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velella#Distribution_and_habitat) (my emphasis):

> Having no means of locomotion other than its sail, *V. velella* is at the mercy of prevailing winds for moving around the seas, and are thereby also subject to **mass-strandings on beaches throughout the world. For example, most years in the spring, there is a mass stranding that occurs along the West Coast of North America**

- You can also see a report about these guys washing up on California beaches in mid-April from the [Orange County Register](https://www.ocregister.com/2021/04/16/rare-sight-strange-jelly-like-creatures-delight-newport-beach-beachgoers/).

Educational video of these sailors available here: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=ZJGO_bSsR3w&embeds_euri=http%3A%2F%2Fsio-legacy.ucsd.edu%2F&source_ve_path=Mjg2NjY&feature=emb_logo)

---

#### Man o' war' is incorrect

Note: my initial gut reaction was that it was a small, beat-up [**Portuguese man o' war**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_man_o%27_war) (*Physalia physalis*), often referred to as the **Pacific man o' war** (or even a "blue bottle") in the Pacific Ocean. A colonial marine [siphonophore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphonophorae)  (within class [Hydrazoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrozoa)) made of many smaller ["zooids"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zooid). Like *Velella*, it also floats on the water surface with its "pneumatophore" (a gas-filled bladder that forms a dorsal "sail" that can be pushed around by wind above the ocean) while tentacles armed with [nematocysts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cnidocyte) dangle below to capture/stun prey.

- Like your specimen, the man o' war's sail (or "pneumatophore") appears to be somewhat translucent with the lower portion often taking on a blue coloration (or sometimes purple, pink, or mauve) [[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_man_o%27_war#Anatomy_and_physiology)] like your organism. It's also not irregular to have many of these wash ashore all at once, as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_man_o%27_war#/media/File:Faja,_Faial,_Azoren_am_26.04.2020.jpg).

[image]

However, the size and morphology (especially small size of the "sail", lack of obviously large bladder, and the clear concentric-circle morphology) of your specimen all pointed to another organism (and clearly toward *Velella* as stated above).

Comment: For what it's worth, NPR had a brief story on By-The-Wind-Sailors this week.